# LINQtoCSV (or Other Libs): How To Export (to CSV file) Dynamic Number of Fields in a Class

Tags: .net, linq, reflection, csv

I think LINQtoCSV is a good lib for saving and loading CSV files.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx

However, I have question, and posted it on the link above, but it seems that the author is not upgrading the lib, and there is no reply to my question.

My question is:

Using LINQtoCSV (or other library), how to export dynamic number of fields in a class

```
public class DynamicNumberFieldsClass
{
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1, Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    // [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2, Name = "Years")]
    // I don't know how to write the CsvColumn attribute
    // because the number of years is dynamic.
    // If the user sets to 10 years, I want to export the CSV files
    // with 11 columns (FullName and 10 years: Year1, Year2,....
    public int[]  Years { get; set; }
}
```

The expected output CSV file:

```
FullName Year1 Year2 Year3...
Peter    11    12    13
Bryan    21    22    23
```

If I have to use reflection, it's okay for me.  But how to use the LINQtoCSV lib with reflection to meet my requirement?

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how to do it with [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), a library I maintain. CsvHelper is available on NuGet.

```
var streamWriter = //...Create your writer
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter( streamWriter );

// Write the header row
csvWriter.WriteField( "Name" );
foreach( var year in myList.First().Years )
{
    csvWriter.WriteField( "Year" + year );
}
csvWriter.NextRecord();

// Write the rest of the rows.
foreach( var item in myList )
{
    csvWriter.WriteField( item.FullName );
    foreach( var year in item.Years )
    {
        csvWriter.WriteField( year );
    }
    csvWriter.NextRecord();
}
```

You obviously want to use a `using` block and check for nulls and all that stuff too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[]  Years { get; set; }

//just create another property
[CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2, Name = "Years")]
public string Years_InString
{
  get { return this.Years
                   .Select(year => year.ToString())
                   .Aggregate((cur, nex) => cur + "," + nex); }
}
```

for large array, use StringBuilder in increase performance.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I'm afraid of that you might have misunderstood my question.  I want the number of fields to be dynamic, not inside the specific field ("Years).